# change hive inode directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to run hive using a user other than the hadoop user.
When I run hive, I get the error below. I guess Hive is trying to access the root directory. How do I change the inode directory to /user/fratboy? I have already created this in hdfs and changed the owner to fratboy.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j- 
impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12- 
1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an 
explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type 
[org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in 
jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-common-2.3.2.jar!/hive- 
log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: 
user=fratboy, access=WRITE, inode="/":hduser:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

Comment: show us your codes so that we know how you created the table and used a different id to execute it

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

if you have root permission: `#sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /`

This will change the permissions on / to `drwxrwxr-x`, which gives permission to your user fratboy.

Make such that the `/user` already exist on `/`

hope this help